# All android project fail to compile on Eclipse - Windows8 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, 64-bit

Just downloaded FacebookSDK - tried to compile and - “R cannot be resolved to a variable” error. Create new empty project - “R cannot be resolved to a variable” error. even when open old working projects - same error. Te only difference is migrated from WindowsXP to Windows8 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. Google just released new update for Android tools - after install all my Windows8 64 bit problems dissapeared!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe clean the project, that it is refreshed to the new eclipse atmosphere? Or did you use the similar software build of eclipse?

Comment: More than 20 projects are published to Google Play from me :) every code that usualy compiles - give me error.